# Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise does not recognize total of 20 GB of RAM

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a HP ProLiant DL 120 G7 installed windows server 2008 r2 enterprise, came from the factory with 4GB of ram (2 GB + 2) and added another 16GB (8 + 8 GB) but the OS shows up with 20 GB total over 4GB usable.

thanks.

---

My operating system is 64-bit.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/229390 ?

Comment: Can you try msconfig > Boot > Advanced, and set Maximum Memory to 20480?

Comment: What does the BIOS show for RAM capacity when you power the server on?

Comment: In the BIOS boot features 4096 MB, but when I enter the BIOS and go to the settings configured it features 20480 MB.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the 32-Bit version of Windows Server 2008 you'll need to turn on PAE to access memory above 4GB.  Here's a URL to Microsoft's documentation on how to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366796%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: My operating system is 64-bit.

Comment: There is no 32bit version of Server 2008 R2!

Comment: I apologize, I never bothered to check if R2 had a 32 bit version.